How to print out floats exactly as what is in the input?
I am asked to complete a task to print out floats exactly as what is in the input. So basically if the input is 1.1 2.2345678 3.3 4.4, then my output must be EXACTLY 1.1 2.2345678 3.3 4.4
Here is my code:

void count_digits(double num) {
    int decimal_whole_part;
    double decimal;
    //char character;
    int final_value;
    decimal = num - (int)num;
    printf(" %d", (int)(num));
    printf(".");
    do{
      decimal_whole_part = (int)(decimal);
      decimal -= decimal_whole_part;
      decimal*=10;
      final_value = (int)(decimal);
      printf("%c", (char)((decimal+32+16)));
    } while((double)(final_value) != (double)(decimal));
}

I tried using floats, but it will result in trailing zeroes, such as 1.100000 2.2345678000000...... and so on(please ignore inconsistent zeroes, they are consistent in the output).I can not use %g, sprintf or truncating the floats. Particularly, I can't use format specifiers because inconsistency in the length of input floats.
I tried separating part before the decimal point and after the decimal point, convert the part after decimal point into ascii code and adding particular value to it to obtain number as a string (sorry for bad English). Again, I did so because the challenging task involves not using sprintf and %g.
My input:
1.11111 2.023 3.043

My output:
1.111110000000000042064129956997931003570556640625 2.023000000000000131450406115618534386157989501953125 3.0430000000000001492139745096210390329360961914062

Desired output:
1.11111 2.023 3.043

Can someone please tell me how to end the loop properly and acquire the desired output? Thanks.
Edit:
I tried reading input as a string. However I also need to read input as floats as I will need to calculate the average of these numbers later on.
This is a school project and we have not yet learnt things like sprintf, %g or atof so I can't use them. Prof advised us to use
scnaf("%lf%c").... as a way to input the data.
Here is my current code:
while(scanf("%c%c", &lect_id, &spacer) == 2){
  comp_array[m] = lect_id;
  n = 0;
  while(scanf("%lf%c", &score, &spacer) == 2){
     score_array[n] = score;
     n++;
     while(scanf("%c%c%c%c", &integer, &dot, &number_after_dot, spacer) == 4){
        converted_array[a] = integer;
        converted_array2[a] = dot;
        converted_array3[a] = number_after_dot;
        a++;
     }
  }
  m++;

}
the result is either a segmentation fault or the number of m is always one.
And the printed strings from the array are incorrect as well.

sorry i meant 2,2345678 corresponds EXACTLY to 2,2345678

desired output for 3.200 is 3.200, for 4 is 4, 4.000 is 4.000

You can work with strings instead of numbers, and output the input string without any processing. That's a bit dull. Probably not what you want, but why? If this idea doesn't solve your problem, please explain why (you can [edit] your question to clarify).

I tried this, but I also need to calculate the average of input number at the same time, so I need to keep an array of floats as well, which when combining them into two while(scanf) loop, does not work.... I also can't use atof

A number is an abstract mathematical entity, such as ten. There are multiple ways of representing each number. For example, ten can be represented as “ten”, “10”, “10.00”, and “1•101”.
A float, double, int, or other C arithmetic type represents only the mathematical value. It does not store information about how the number is represented.1
Therefore, it is impossible to reliably reconstruct the original representation of a number from a C arithmetic type. In particular, you cannot distinguish “1.1” from “1.100000”.
Additionally, C implementations commonly use a binary-based format for double, and the most commonly used format, IEEE-754 binary64 (“double precision”), cannot represent the number 1.1. The nearest representable value is 1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625.
To remember the input form, you should record the input as a string of characters. Create a character array for each numeral in the input and store the characters of the input item in the array. Mark the end with a null character (or remember the length).

… abnormally behaved do while loop…

This has nothing to do with the do loop, and its behavior is not abnormal.
Footnote
1 It is possible for an arithmetic type to store some limited information about how a number is represented. IEEE-754 decimal floating-point formats have multiple representations for many numbers, differing in the exponent used. There is no standard C interface for this, and it would not serve your purposes.

But when I was simulating the loop on paper, it was working as intended....

@acd123: It is quite likely you did not correctly implement the semantics of double in your work on paper. Most C implementations use a binary-based format for double, and using a decimal format on paper will not reproduce that behavior.

@acd123: Using a double format with good knowledge about how it operates could reproduce some decimal inputs exactly, but it definitely cannot distinguish between numerals with different numbers of trailing zeros, such as “1.1” and “1.100”. To perform the task stated in the question, you must record the input as a string (or other supplementary information beyond a C arithmetic type).

But the input must be doubles...

@acd123: Input to C programs is in the form of sequences of bytes, not double objects. All input obtained via getchar, fread, and other file operations is in the form of sequences of bytes. “1.1” in the input is not a double. It is the characters “1”, “.”, and “1”.

But I am only allowed to use scanf, I need to store spaces as well so scanf("%lf%c"), thats what I was advised to do...

@acd123 If someone advised you to use scanf, you should be forever suspect of advice from that person.  If you must use scanf for some reason (eg, a course requirement), then you ought to use %s and read the data as a string.  (Make sure you use a with modifier, eg "%127s").  Read a string and write a string, and don't ever convert to a numeric type.

@acd123 But I am only allowed to use scanf, I need to store spaces as well so scanf("%lf%c"), thats what I was advised to do...  And just how would that tell you the difference between 100 and 1E2?  Or 42.0100 and 0042.01?

Just to emphasize what has already been posted:
When you convert a string such as 1.1000 into a numeric variable such as a double, you lose information about the input.
First, as already noted in comments and other answer, the resulting value stored is not guaranteed to be an exact representation of the value represented by the input string.  As stated, 1.1000 will actually be stored as 1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625 if your system uses IEEE-754 binary64 values.
Second, you also lose information from the format, such as leading or trailing zeroes.  Or 1E2 compared to 100 - value stored will be the same but the information on how the input was formatted has been lost.
The input string 1.1 and the input string 1.100 and the input string 1.1000000000000000888178 will all  be stored the same in a double, and you have no way to tell what the input string was.
You cannot just save the value into a double - a double variable simply does not contain the information necessary to do so.  If someone tells you it's possible they simply do not understand what they are saying.
The easiest way to reproduce the exact input string is to simply save the exact input string.
You could also create some scheme to save the information necessary to reproduce the input string, but that would be a lot harder than simply saving a copy of the input string and would likely require more memory then the string anyway.

You are entering decimal real numbers and storing them in a double precision binary floating point data type, the round-trip conversion back to decimal will not preserve more than 15 significant figures due to the nature of the binary representation.
The following formats a string to the maximum number of significant decimal digits (the ones double can accurately retain), and adds or removes trailing zeros as required.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX_SIG_DIGITS 15
char* double_to_string( double num, char* str )
{
    *str = '\0' ;
    int int_digits = (int)ceil(log10( fabs(num) )) ;
    int decimal_places = MAX_SIG_DIGITS - int_digits ;
    
    // Round integers with > 15 digits with trailing zeros                     
    if( decimal_places < 0 )
    {
        double decimal_shift = pow( 10, -decimal_places ) ;
        num = round( num / decimal_shift) * decimal_shift ;
        decimal_places = 0 ;
    }
    
    // Format i.f string to maximum number of significant digits                    
    int end_index = sprintf( str, "%*.*lf", int_digits, decimal_places, num ) - 1 ;
    
    // Trim trailing fraction zeros
    while( decimal_places > 1 && str[end_index] == '0' )
    {
        decimal_places-- ;
        str[end_index] = '\0' ;
        end_index-- ;
    }

    return str ;
}

The following example usage has an array of decimal string examples as might be input by your user.  They are then converted to double via sscanf() before being formatted by the above function, thus performing the the round-trip conversion:
int main()
{
    const char* examples[] = 
    { 
        "1.1",
        "2.2345678",
        "3.3",
        "4.4",
        "1.11111",
        "2.023",
        "3.043",
        "12345678901234567.0",
        "1.12345678901234567",
        "123.00000456",
        "9.99999",
        "9.9999999999999999",

        "-1.1",
        "-2.2345678",
        "-3.3",
        "-4.4",
        "-1.11111",
        "-2.023",
        "-3.043",
        "-12345678901234567.0",
        "-1.12345678901234567",
        "-123.00000456",
        "-9.99999",
        "-9.9999999999999999"
    } ;
              
    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(examples) / sizeof(*examples); i++ )
    {
        char dblstr[20] = {0} ;
        double dbl = 0.0 ;
        sscanf( examples[i], "%lf", &dbl ) ;
        printf( "%-22s%s\n", examples[i], 
                             double_to_string( dbl, dblstr ) ) ;
    }

    return 0;
}

The example output is:
1.1                   1.1
2.2345678             2.2345678
3.3                   3.3
4.4                   4.4
1.11111               1.11111
2.023                 2.023
3.043                 3.043
12345678901234567.0   12345678901234600
1.12345678901234567   1.12345678901235
123.00000456          123.00000456
9.99999               9.99999
9.9999999999999999    10.0
-1.1                  -1.1
-2.2345678            -2.2345678
-3.3                  -3.3
-4.4                  -4.4
-1.11111              -1.11111
-2.023                -2.023
-3.043                -3.043
-12345678901234567.0  -12345678901234600
-1.12345678901234567  -1.12345678901235
-123.00000456         -123.00000456
-9.99999              -9.99999
-9.9999999999999999   -10.0

Observe that when the input has fewer then 15 significant digits the output is the same as the input.  For input with more that 15 significant digits, it rounds to 15 significant digits, which is the best you can hope for when using double.

You have several requirements which make your task pointless.
Here is an outline of how you could accomplish your task:

Read a string from the user (scanf)
Store this string so you could output it later (strdup)
Convert the string to a floating-point number (strtod, atof or sscanf)
Calculate whatever you need to calculate
Print the initial string (printf)

You are not allowed to use some of the tools above because of teaching reasons. It might be possible to implement your task without these tools, but that would make the code less understandable, which contradicts what you are trying to do (learning). So I suggest throwing away your requirements. Specifically, the one about preserving input format.
Since you tried formats like "%c%c%c%c", and you are working with "scores" of some kind, maybe you can assume 2 decimal digits and be done with it. Keep this new requirement simple so it would let you concentrate on the really important stuff (the calculations).
double value;
scanf("%lf", &value);
printf("%4.2f", value);
// 4 -> 4.00
// 3.157 -> 3.16
// 99 -> 99.00

Another good compromise would be %g format (which you are not allowed to use, but this restriction is silly and I invite you to ignore it).
If the important stuff in your project is actually the input/output and formatting, then please don't use this answer. But be prepared for a world of pain — C is not the right tool if you want to do correct formatting on user input (output is OK though).

In step 3, I wouldn't recommend atof() - other than as a learning experience to discover why it's unusable when zero is a valid input.

This works for many inputs 1.1, 1.100, -008.1, 321 and 321.
It uses scansets and the %n specifier.
the scanset %1[+-] will scan one character that must be either + or -.
the scanset &*[0] scans and discards zeros
the %n specifier counts the number of characters processed in the scan.
Output is printed using the width and precision fields. %0*.*f prints necessary leading zeros in a field length characters wide with a precision of decimals. The asterisks allow the use of variables to provide the width and precision.
For multiple inputs, sign, value, length and decimals would need to be stored. A structure could be used for that.
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void) {
    char sign = 0;
    int leadingzeros = 0;
    int length = 0;
    int digits = 0;
    int decimals = 0;
    int whole = 0;
    double value = 0.0;

    if ( 1 != scanf ( " %1[+-]", &sign)) { // scan and discard leading whitespace try to scan a sign
        sign = ' ';
    }
    leadingzeros = 0;
    scanf ( "%*[0]%n", &leadingzeros); // scan and discard zeros but count them
    length = 0;
    if ( 1 == scanf ( "%lf%n", &value, &length)) { // scan a double and count length of imput
        whole = (int)value;
        while ( whole) { // count number of digits before .
            ++digits;
            whole /= 10;
        }
        decimals = length - digits;
        length -= ( decimals == 1); // only a . remains
        decimals -= ( decimals != 0); // subtract one for .
        length += leadingzeros;
        printf ( "\t%c%0*.*f\n", sign, length, decimals, value);
    }

    return 0;
}

Example of multiple inputs with a structure
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 5

typedef struct {
    double value;
    int length;
    int decimals;
    char sign;
} formedoutput;

int main ( void) {
    int leadingzeros = 0;
    int digits = 0;
    int scanned = 0;
    int whole = 0;
    int entry = 0;
    formedoutput out[SIZE] = { 0};

    do {
        printf ( "enter %d floating point value as xxx.xx\n", SIZE - entry);
        if ( 1 != ( scanf ( " %1[+-]", &out[entry].sign))) { // scan and discard leading whitespace try to scan a sign
            out[entry].sign = 0; // scan failed set default
        }
        leadingzeros = 0;
        scanf ( "%*[0]%n", &leadingzeros); // scan and discard zeros but count them
        out[entry].length = 0;
        if ( 1 == ( scanned = scanf ( "%lf%n", &out[entry].value, &out[entry].length))) { // scan a double and count length of imput
            whole = (int)out[entry].value;
            digits = 0;
            while ( whole) {
                ++digits;
                whole /= 10;
            }
            out[entry].decimals = out[entry].length - digits;
            out[entry].length -= ( out[entry].decimals == 1); // only . remains
            out[entry].decimals -= ( out[entry].decimals != 0); // subtract for .
            out[entry].length += leadingzeros;
        }
        entry += ( scanned == 1);
    } while ( scanned == 1 && entry < SIZE);

    int loop = 0;
    while ( loop < entry) {
        printf ( "\t%c%0*.*f\n", out[loop].sign, out[loop].length, out[loop].decimals, out[loop].value);
        ++loop;
    }

    return 0;
}  

Results
enter 5 floating point value as xxx.xx
01.100
enter 4 floating point value as xxx.xx
-09.87654321
enter 3 floating point value as xxx.xx
97531
enter 2 floating point value as xxx.xx
1.1
enter 1 floating point value as xxx.xx
0.321
    01.100
    -09.87654321
    97531
    1.1
    0.321


for example, if you want to display 2 digits after the decimal point use:
double decInitial = 75.5678;
double decFinal = ((int)decInitial*100)/100;
this outputs 75.56
